# Java android room get java objects from two tables

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have a two tables and I want to get one Java objects.

This is my table one:

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
long id;
@ColumnInfo(name = "date")
String date;
@ColumnInfo(name = "azimuth")
int azimuth;
```

and this is my table two :

```
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    long id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    String name;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "symbol")
    String symbol;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    String type;
```

And id from table one is this same that id table 3

and I want to get query in which I have a this class :

```
long id;
String date;
int azimuth;
String name;
String symbol;
String type;
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the question, what do you want to do?

Comment: @user8468173 I have to tables and I want to join this to tables  like table1.id = table2.id

Comment: You can use query to join 2 tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a data class say `ResultTable` that contains the fields you want:

```
public class ResultTable{
    long id;
    String date;
    int azimuth;
    String name;
    String symbol;
    String type;
}
```

Now you can query the data from two tables and get the result into the above table, as below;

```
@Query("SELECT id, t1.date as date, t1.azimuth as azimuth, t2.name as name, t2.symbol as symbol, t2.type as type FROM tabel1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t1.id = :id")
List<ResultTable> performJoinQuery(long id)
```